# How to draw rounded rectangle with variable width border inside of specific bounds

Tags: c#, gdi+, rounded-corners

I have a method that draws a rounded rectangle with a border. The border can be any width, so the problem I'm having is the border is extending past the given bounds when it's thick because it's drawn from the center of a path.

How would I include the width of the border so that it fits perfectly in the given bounds?

Here's the code I'm using to draw the rounded rectangle.

```
private void DrawRoundedRectangle(Graphics gfx, Rectangle Bounds, int CornerRadius, Pen DrawPen, Color FillColor)
{
    GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath();

    DrawPen.EndCap = DrawPen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 180, 90);
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 270, 90);
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 0, 90);
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 90, 90);
    gfxPath.CloseAllFigures();

    gfx.FillPath(new SolidBrush(FillColor), gfxPath);
    gfx.DrawPath(DrawPen, gfxPath);
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Alright guys, I figured it out! Just need to shrink the bounds to take into account the width of the pen. I kind of knew this was the answer I was just wondering if there was a way to draw a line on the inside of a path. This works good though.

```
private void DrawRoundedRectangle(Graphics gfx, Rectangle Bounds, int CornerRadius, Pen DrawPen, Color FillColor)
{
    int strokeOffset = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(DrawPen.Width));
    Bounds = Rectangle.Inflate(Bounds, -strokeOffset, -strokeOffset);

    DrawPen.EndCap = DrawPen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;

    GraphicsPath gfxPath = new GraphicsPath();
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 180, 90);
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 270, 90);
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X + Bounds.Width - CornerRadius, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 0, 90);
    gfxPath.AddArc(Bounds.X, Bounds.Y + Bounds.Height - CornerRadius, CornerRadius, CornerRadius, 90, 90);
    gfxPath.CloseAllFigures();

    gfx.FillPath(new SolidBrush(FillColor), gfxPath);
    gfx.DrawPath(DrawPen, gfxPath);
}
```