# Draw a 3D border

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I would like to draw a 3D border (bevel) using GDI+, for example inside the `Paint` event of a `Control`. Should I write it by myself using `DrawLine` and `KnownColors` or there is something ready to use?

Thanks
Saied

Comment: It's his first question here! ;) @SaidMohamed start reading the FAQ. If you provide a well-formed question you'll get a better answer, quickly. Start with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: oh my God I didn't see that comment ,I am so sorry about that ,the problem is that I am currently working in another project and I put that project a side but until now there is no way to solve this problem but I will make sure to try to solve it and if I did I will post the answer for sure.

Answer (score 5):

What are you using to draw? GDI+ on WinForms? If that's the case you can use the [ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder3d.aspx) method, for example in the `Paint` event handler:

```
ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(e.Graphics,
    ((Control)sender).ClientRectangle,
    Border3DStyle.Bump);
```

See the [Border3DStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.border3dstyle.aspx) enumeration for the list of all available styles.

Comment: Thank you very much that really helps a lot,I would like to know how can I draw a round rectangle as well if u can help that would be very appreciated

Comment: @saidmohamed For rounded rectangles you can check this post here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628261/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-with-variable-width-border-inside-of-specific-boun

Comment: @saidmohamed more or less ;) DrawRoundedRectangle(e.Graphics, rect, 10, Color.Black, Color.White);

Comment: oops miss understanding ,problem solved hehe :D

Comment: can I make this round rectangle bevel ,I am trying to do it right now but if u know the answer I would really appreciated it .

Comment: @saidmohamed no, the DrawBorder3D function is based on the native DrawEdge function, it doesn't support rounded rectangles. You have to do it "by hand" using the function from that post and two different colors (light and shadow). For an example look the disassemble (or the source code) of the ControlPaint.DrawBorder method.