# how to draw scalene triangle with rounded corners

Tags: c#, graphics, rounded-corners

Anyone know how to draw an arbitrary scalene triangle with rounded corners?  Preferably in c#?

This is an example for rectangles: [How to draw rounded rectangle with variable width border inside of specific bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628261/how-to-draw-rounded-rectangle-with-variable-width-border-inside-of-specific-boun)

I'd like to do the same thing for triangles.

Comment: You should be able to just do the same thing, but with three arcs instead of four.

Comment: That would only work for angles of 90 degrees or wider.  I'm looking for a general solution.

Comment: You would have to calculate the inside angles. In fact, it wouldn't be too much of a stretch to make that code work for arbitrary polygons...

Comment: I'd like to see your source code, then.  I don't think it will work.